# CSS overlapping arrow

Tags: css

I'm trying to accomplish something very, very similar to the below picture with CSS3 only.

[image]

The only difference is that the last div would have a pointed tip.

In my search for something similar to adapt, I've come across [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/eju9r/14/) which comes very close to what I want to do, but introduces two problems: first, it's done with canvas, and second, it forces me to "draw" arrows effectively twice for each arrow -- one for the div, and one for the space before the next arrow. There has to be some cleaner way of doing this -- can someone provide me with some direction here?

What I need to know is how to construct what's shown in the above picture -- a series of overlapping div arrows -- with CSS3 only.

Comment: is using a background image for each of the arrows not an option for the above? =>|>=>|>=  The arrows above don't actually overlap.

Comment: @marabutt I guess they might not -- it sort of looks like the end of each arrow meets the tail of the next to me though. In either case I want to do overlap.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/ksNr3/8/

```
ul {
    margin: 20px 60px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px 1px 0 0;
    text-indent: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}

ul li:first-child:before {
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul li a:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul li.active a {
    background: orange;
    z-index: 100;
}

ul li.active a:after {
    border-left-color: orange;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: pink;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent pink; 
}
​
```

**UPDATED**  -  Made it clickable and minimized the overlapping areas - http://jsfiddle.net/ksNr3/8/

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. That was unbelievably helpful.

Comment: @arttronics The arrows appear to belong to the wrong element because of how they overlap. When you inspect the elements with Firebug, it is highlighting the space each element occupies on the page, regardless of whether or not that space is visible to the user. Notice that the `:before` and `:after` [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) that make the triangles are not actually highlighted with the `li` elements. The solution suggested is working as intended.

Comment: @arttronics Ah, my mistake I see what you mean now. You're right, I hadn't noticed that before. The triangles are made by setting 3 border sides to transparent, which are still treated as being part of the element on `mouseover` even if they are not visible. I'm not sure about an easy fix, but a workaround might be to put the text in `<a>` tags and attach `mouseover` event to those? Not the desired behavior, but at least there is no confusion over which breadcrumb you're hovering over.

Comment: Just a tip: if you move the .active styling so that it is below the hover styling, then the active link won't appear as though it is clickable. This is often good UX considering that the active style shows the page you are currently on.

Comment: @arttronics Oh, I didn't even realise that was an issue, I was talking about something completely different. I'll have a look at that now.

Comment: does each arrow have to be a fixed width?  change one of the texts to "foo bar biff bam boom" and it breaks.  i am trying to update the fiddle to allow for variable widths (some can be short and others long) without using javascript but still no luck...

Comment: +1 to this solution because it is the cleanest and best one out there

Comment: okay you can remove the fixed width of 100px but then need to wrap the text in a span to correctly position it -- here is the updated sample  --  http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/ksNr3/1060/

Answer (score 7):

The following CSS3 Solution **does not use any images** and is easy to work with.

I have created **TWO** fully commented examples that can be expanded further.

One example has arrows that are "visually" stacked against each other.

The other example is *just like the image* in your Question, with "end-caps" on the arrows.

Each example has a simple jQuery `.click()` event listener so you can see no matter where you are clicking in the **breadcrumb**, the anchor will receive the correct click event. Arrow tails work correctly.

**Screenshot shows active CSS hover for NavBar's breadcrumb:**

[image]

When CSS is disabled in the browser, the breadcrumb navigation gracefully falls back for accessibility requirements.

**Reference:**    [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vrys/)

Comment: For a similar **Breadcrumb NavBAR** without the CSS3 Rotation I made, see this [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11218781/1195891).