# Descend z-index logically

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

```
<div id="crumbs">

<a href="#" style="z-index: 4;">Workplace Standards</a> &#62;
<a href="#" style="z-index: 3;">Resources</a> &#62;
<a href="#" style="z-index: 2;">Guides</a> &#62;
<a href="#" style="z-index: 1;">Public holidays</a>

</div>
```

I have a simple breadcrumb nav, can JQuery assign a descending z-index to each link in the div like the code above? Currently prints the links with no z-index so they look bad.

How I want it to look:

[image: How I want it to look]

How it currently looks:

[image]

CSS

The only real key players in the CSS are the position and margin-left, but here it is in its entirety :)

```css
#crumbs a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 1em 2em 2em 1em;
    margin-left: -.6em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, CSS has been added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Status Update:**   If **CSS** and **JavaScript** are disabled then proper *fallback* for `breadcrumbs` will occur.

**Reference:**   [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWWyP/)

**Screenshot of CSS and JavaScript Enabled:**
[image]

**Screenshot of CSS and JavaScript Disabled:**

[image]

*Extra: If a CSS3 version is acceptable, I was inspired to make a version with Arrows at this [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282225/1195891).*

---

**EDIT:**

Extra [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rfsLE/) with alternate style by [*Simon Sarris*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034513/1195891).

[image]

Comment: Worth considering I guess, as a pure CSS fix. However, it's a very bad idea (for accessibility, and possibly also for SEO) to have *breadcrumb links* in reverse order in the HTML.

Comment: Hi unfortunately this doesn't meet our accessibility requirements, but thanks for taking the time to have a go anyway :)

Comment: Pretty straight forward mate, imagine a screen-reader reading the crumbs, in your case it'll start with the last one first and read backwards. Australian Government websites must meet certain usability standards. If CSS is disabled by the user, the page should print basic crumbs ie. Item 1 > Item 2 > Item 3. Not Item 3 > Item 2 > Item 1

Comment: @user1038627, please check out my latest [**jsFiddle Update**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWWyP/). Thank you!

Comment: That's an impressive solution, thank you :) I ended up wrapping the '>' in spans and used css display none to hide them so they appear during fallback. Thanks mate :)

Comment: Thank you! I am glad to have help you with this method. Please take a peek if you ever need a CSS3 version, that alternate link is in my answer above. Cheers!

Comment: I did check it out and I wish I had seen it earlier. I had given up on the pointy tips which is why I decided on the border-radius instead. Looks a little funny but figured my users would just have to get used to it, disabled users are more my concern and as long as they see "1 > 2 > 3" then it's all good. You're a clever cookie!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$($('#crumbs > a').get().reverse()).css('z-index', function(index) {
    return index+1;
});
```

Or, if you'd prefer to loop with `.each()`:

```
$($('#crumbs > a').get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('z-index', index+1);
});​​
```

Note that for this to work, you'll need to ensure that your `a` elements have `position: relative`.

Comment: Thanks mate, does that assign a z-index to each link and then reverse the z-index order? Just checking because as I said the links currently print with *no* z-index. I can assign a z-index to them but it'll be the same z-index for every link :/

Comment: Yes, this does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yep, CSS has position: relative, I know how to use z-index, thank you :) Still, applying the script to the page generates no z-index's in the source so I must be implementing it wrong. Thanks for the idea though I'll try another method :)

Comment: @user1038627: Did you wrap the code in `.ready()`? `$(document).ready(function() { /* the code goes here */ });`. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HtFWL/2/

Comment: @user1038627: If your HTML structure is different to what's in your question, change `$('#crumbs > a')` to `$('#crumbs a')`.

Comment: @thirtydot, how do you call up syntax highlighting in Question edit?

Comment: @arttronics: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. CSS code is never automatically highlighted. [It's rather annoying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions), and it doesn't seem like it's going to be fixed any time soon. I wouldn't have bothered adding the syntax highlight, except that doing so insta-approved your edit.

Comment: @thirtydot When removing the '>' your script works perfectly, thank you. I neglected to mention that the '>' is in a span that is set to display:none in the CSS so when the user disables CSS, it prints a nice basic crumb ie. Item 1 > Item 2 > Item 3. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Without positioning z-index is pretty much useless

```
<div id="crumbs">

    <a href="#" style="position:relative;z-index: 4;">Workplace Standards</a> &#62;
    <a href="#" style="position:relative;z-index: 3;">Resources</a> &#62;
    <a href="#" style="position:relative;z-index: 2;">Guides</a> &#62;
    <a href="#" style="position:relative;z-index: 1;">Public holidays</a>

</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HtFWL/1/)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index)

Comment: Thanks but the position is handled in the CSS for good reason. When a user disables CSS the crumbs will print traditionally ie. Item > Item > Item