# For mobile safari and mobile webkit in general, is it better to use complex CSS or an image

Tags: performance, css, mobile, memory-management, responsive-design

I asked this question recently: [How can I create a CSS border on a diagonal element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782432/how-can-i-create-a-css-border-on-a-diagonal-element/13783241)

**Question:** Is it more memory intensive or cpu intensive to use image or complex css for a navigation menu?

**Question:** Cross browser/screen size aside, is the an advantage to one over the other for reasons other than what is mentioned above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the device needs to display an array of pixels. If you send an image file of those pixels, they are ready for display. If you send complex css for creating those pixels, it will likely take fewer bytes across the network but the processor will need to render the pixel array before it can be displayed.

Whether you should use css or an image depends on a variety of considerations. Here are a few:

- Is the thing you need to display always exactly the same size? Then an image file has the advantage of already being rendered. If not, css will give the capability to size efficiently.
- Will the user always have a good network connection? If so, there won't be as much of a performance penalty for sending a pre-rendered image and possibly a bunch of media query css to decide which image to load.
- Is the thing you are trying to render very large on screen? If so, css might have an advantage over loading a large image file.
- Is the css extremely complex, taking lots of code to describe? Then an image file has the cpu advantage of being pre-processed.
- Are there animation states or other animation associated with the display item? Then css has the advantage of not having to load multiple potentially large image files. But, if the states have very complex animation taking lots of code and therefore cpu, then the previous guideline will apply.

Second question: If there are cross-browser difficulties with your css, a pre-rendered image will eliminate those. But, if you are building a responsive display object that has very many different display sizes, css will have the advantage of scalability. That said, a basic concept in responsive design would be to provide a few different size versions of an image.

In general, image files cost bandwidth and css/vectors cost cpu.