# Expandable, non-rectangular CSS button?

Tags: css, html

After much poking around online, I've found lots of advice and examples for using CSS to style submit buttons, but they all result in rectangular buttons.  I want to make a non-rectangular button that automatically sizes itself to fit the button legend.  Specifically, I want the button to look like this (plus or minus the rounded corners):

[image: Non-rectangular button]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into generating a triangle with a pseudo-element?

Comment: http://cssnerd.com/2011/11/30/the-best-pure-css3-ios-style-arrow-back-button/ Using css shadowing curves etc

Comment: you'll need to either use an image, or as @ScottSimpson suggests, look into making css triangles. `border-radius:0 30px 30px 0` won't do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here is a [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282225/1195891) I made for breadcrumb navigation that gracefully falls back for accessibility requirements, but it's CSS3.

Comment: What is the lesser IE version you need to support? @Nate thanks for the link, will prove useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally possible with border radius, but you will have to submit with JavaScript instead of the `<button>` element.

For instance:

```
.icon {
background-color: lightblue;
width: 100px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 10px;

border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;

border-top-right-radius: 60px 22px;    
-moz-border-radius-topright: 60px 22px;   
border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 22px;   
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 60px 22px;
}
```

Makes:

[image]

See it live:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zamA/

Comment: **+1** Excellent CSS3 solution! Using **your answer** with extra code I had in another [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11218781/1195891) produces this new [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rfsLE/). Note the HTML inner contents is to enhance accessibility fallback to show graphic arrow. Cheers!

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I'm not crazy about the bullet-shaped, rounded corners though.  Seems to my neophyte mind that we should be able to create a rectangular "container" that contains a colored rectangle containing the button legend and an adjacent triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS border triangle trick: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

You could use svg.

Comment: **-1** No rounded corners or images per OP requirements.

Comment: Technically, the OP does not say that images and/or rounded corners are not allowed.  The only requirement is that the button is not rectangular and scales with the text.

Comment: Thanks allyourcode.  Yes, you are right, I kind of like the rounded corners, but I'm really interested in getting a rectangle hooked onto a triangle.