# Parallelogram navigation background with CSS

Tags: css, background, nav

I'm trying to create this nav menu (green highlight is the active page, gray is hover state):

[image: Nav Menu]

I can make the parallelogram with the following CSS:

```
ul#nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 10px;
    border-radius:3px;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    color:#757575;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
    background:#f3f1eb;
}

ul#nav li a.current-menu-item {
    color:#fff;
    background:#5d9732;
}

ul#nav li a.current-menu-item:hover {
    background:#5d9732;
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes the text to skew as well, appearing italic:

[image: Nav Menu Skewed]

Here's a jsfiddle showing the setup (although the skew doesn't work in jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/K3bQJ/4/

Is there any way to prevent the skew of the text, so it doesn't appear italic? I'm loading jQuery but would prefer to avoid it or at least have a usable CSS fallback.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: For future reference, there's http://cssdesk.com/ which is just for CSS and HTML without the Javascript component. I think it's pretty nice for this kind of testing.

Comment: I'm not able to test this right now, but how about placing the visual effects on the li-element, such as background-color and transform, then setting transform:none on the anchor element?

Comment: Apply `display: inline-block;` in the jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/K3bQJ/5/

Comment: Interesting problem. You know, sometimes it's really cool to just use and image :)

Comment: **+1**  **Side Note:** For alternate CSS3 navigation method using ***arrows***, see my [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282225/1195891). Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/K3bQJ/6/) Add a span inside your  tags and set it's skew to the opposite direction (note the use of skewX which is considered correct according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform)

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="current-menu-item" href="#"><span>Nav Item 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Nav Item 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Nav Item 3</span></a></li>
</ul>

ul#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 10px;
    border-radius:3px;
            transform: skewX(-10deg);
         -o-transform: skewX(-10deg);
       -moz-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    color:#757575;
}

ul#nav li a span {
    display: inline-block;
            transform: skewX(10deg);
         -o-transform: skewX(10deg);
       -moz-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

Comment: Had that same thought, except tried it on the `a` instead of wrapping with a span.

Comment: Perfect, this works! I just added the background styles to the li instead of the a element to avoid adding more markup, then set the reverse skew to the anchor element. Thanks so much!

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform you shouldn't use skew() but instead supply the intended axis you are trying to skew (in this case skewX())  I've updated the cssdesk.com link

Comment: **+1** Great Answer. FYI: Last comment you made Jason is important since Firefox v14 dropped transform skew(). I think your **cssdesk.com** demo should be part of your answer too. Cheers!