# Breadcrumb active link css

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

Here is the breadcrumb design I am trying to get but how to get the activated css with arrrow effect, like how it is working for hover

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqTyA/4/)

Comment: Although this Question already has an accepted answer, please see my previous [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282225/1195891) with a solution that you seek (complete with 2 different jsFiddles). Note that hovering on the arrows tail will be for that same Arrow, not the previous. Cheers!

Comment: *Reminder:* Please Upvote any answer when "This answer is useful" is true for you. The Answer you Accepted is lacking your upvote. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a radio button (which you'll hide) and a label in order to achieve that behaviour. The "active" one will be the `:checked` radio button.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/uqTyA/5/) works and it is just CSS3.

If you need to keep the current structure, then you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I need solution for my existing problem, not experiment with anything. Sorry

Comment: Cool but I dont need arrow for the last item. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uqTyA/6/ It's done by setting both the `background-color` and the `border-left-color` to `#afab9d` for `#vert_menu li:last-child label::after`

Comment: **+1** Excellent answer of using radio button to detect which is selected.